# .net membership authentication fails after first attempt / successful login

Tags: .net, authentication, membership

I'm creating an SSO system using .net membership.  I've successfully authenticated users, however, the problem is that once a user logs in, if the user logs out, then tries to login again, the next login attempt fails ("your login attempt was not successful").

E.G. From default login page, (using the .net Login control) user logs in/authenticates and is redirected to loginstatus.aspx. User logs out from loginstatus.aspx (using .net Login Status control) and is redirected to default login page again. User attempts to login again with same credentials, authentication fails.

In local debugging, each time I start and stop debugging, this "clears" the issue and the user can authenticate only once again.  I've tried this on the server too with the same result. Also, if the first authentication attempt fails (bad password), the user cannot login when using a good password on the next attempt.

I'm not customizing or overriding any of the Login control methods (though I've tried membership.validateuser on login.authenticate and ran into the same issue).

I'm using version 6.2.3.0 of MySQLMembershipProvider (I've read about some issues with Hashed passwords and MySqlMembershipProviders, but adding SHA1 doesn't affect the issue, and a user can authenticate once - [MySQL Forms Authentication Hashed password problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090476/mysql-forms-authentication-hashed-password-problem)).

Any tips to debug what might be occurring?

Here is a sample of my web.config (I've also used AutoGenerate machine keys, issue remains):

```
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
         connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" 
         applicationName="myapp" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="8" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="2"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <machineKey validationKey="AD45EA85C19163E399E0ACEBC5523A9C740EFFF42154518FCDFA349E415DF51894C2CA25ABF8CF419C9F206DBE4878118D8BE8CF4DAA2E9708E7296B288ED980" 
            decryptionKey="C1ECCEF762BABCC02A44CD50571C2C3EDF6E7E4F7208886ACE157EF22AFCA27A" 
            validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was something screwy with the database schema.  I updated to mysql connector v 6.5.5.0, the parser threw an error about mysqlroleprovider "missing or incorrect schema", I let it auto generate schema, new schema was created (with no capital letters in table names this time), and the problem appears to be solved.